# How to modify WCF service configuration if services hosted on IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, servicehost

I have WCF service (NET 4) hosted on IIS. It configured via web.config.
I just want to make some little changes at existsing configuration in *runtime*.
It seems using custom ServiceHostFactory/ServiceHost force me to duplicate all settings in code. Is there any trick?

Comment: If you modify the configuration file during runtime, you will restart the application.  In this case, you have two options - either do the configuration in code, or store the configuration information in a separate file, but then you'll have to read a separate file and may have to create the code to do that.  Easier to do it in the code for this scenario, IMO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have a `ServiceHostfatory` :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"   
                Service="IISHost.HelloService"   
                CodeBehind="/App_code/HelloService.svc.cs" 
                Factory="MyServiceHostFactory" %>
```

and you can have a `ServiceHostFactory` that instanciates you service.
Because you instanciate your service "as usual" you can have some code that reads the XML configuration -look at code in the comments below :

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory{
 protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses ) {
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService ));
    // add/modify the endpoints, Behaviors, ... through  
    // host.Description.Endpoints, host.Description.Behaviors …
    return host;
 }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I need!